# How to test data toggle (bootstrap) using jasmine test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have written an ajax to add a question on a page without reloading it. The question has a bootstrap watcher for which I had to write these two lines to show -

```
$("#end-of-list").before(result);
$("[data-toggle='toggle']").bootstrapToggle('destroy')
$("[data-toggle='toggle']").bootstrapToggle();
```

Now, I have to write unit tests for the toggle using jasmine. 
I have written jasmine test for the first line testing the before call in the ajax like this-

```
it("addQuestion should add result before the element with id of end-of-list 
    when ajax call is successful",function () {
    $('<div id="end-of-list"></div>').appendTo("body");
    spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake(function (addQuestion) {
    addQuestion.success('<div id="returned-div"> 
    </div>');
    });
    addQuestion();
    expect($("#end-of-list").prev().attr("id")).toEqual("returned-div");               });
```

But, I have no idea how to test the toggle. If anyone can help that would be great.
Thanks!